# robot.input is not entering text on dockerized browser

Tags: karate

I encountered an issue while running my UI test cases on dockerized browsers. When I using 'robot.input(value)' for entering a text(input and value function not working for me), then instead of entering value on docker browsers it is entering text on my host windows browser. I am using the karate **0.9.6** version.

This is working fine in a normal browser.

Not sure if this issue is solved in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `robot` and `driver` is not proven especially for Docker.

Please consider helping us troubleshoot and solve this problem, this is an open-source project.